# Draw very large Curve on a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have an Application which shows the User some Kind of Curves... I have a List of Points, each point has coordinates(x,y)...

My Layout is one Big Panel, which is set to autoScroll = true, and 4 other panels inside this parent Panel! Every Panel of these 4, shows a curve!

Sometimes it could be possible, that the distance of the first- and the endpoint is larger than the max. height of the Panel,  which results in that i can´t show the whole curve!

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Implement scaling. And maybe Pan and Zoom as well.

Comment: i already implemented scaling...But one of my requirements is to have a fixed scale, for example 1:50...

Comment: @chrizstone if the fixed scale is required, your curve may not be seen wholly via your small screen (17, 20, 25, or even 70 inches). So using some kind of scrolling or pan (used commonly in Map application) is required to allow your user to view different parts of your curve.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, i know what you mean, but i really don´t have an idea how to implement this...:/